# Make change to Tkinter window

Tags: python, tkinter

I am writing my own GUI with Tkinter. I have visited many websites but I couldn't find out how to "make change" to a Tkinter window. For instance, I have a dropdown menu here:

```
var = StringVar();var.set("Select your iPhone")
options1 = ["         b1        ", "   b2     "," b3", "    b4    ","         b5        ","    b6    ","         b7       "]
option2= ["b8"]
optionmenu1=OptionMenu(root, var, *(options1)).pack()
optionmenu2=OptionMenu(root, var, *(option2)).pack()
```

I want like this: If I press a button, the dropdown menu will change from optionmenu1 to optionmenu2, but I couldn't solve this problem. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Thank you so so so much. I have been looking for this for hours!

Comment: Btw I just Googled *tkinter change options in optionmenu* and that was the first answer.

Comment: I couldn't think what should I have to write to Google that time :D